# View showing related nodes before unrelated nodes

Tags: views

I'm trying to create a view, which will show constant number of nodes.
I want it to show related nodes first, and after them (if there aren't enough related nodes) to show other nodes.
As far as i understand, contextual filters will remove all the unrelated nodes and I can't find sort order which will promote related nodes to the top.

Is there any way of doing this with views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[similarterms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms) might fit your bill. If not, [here is a comparison](http://drupal.org/node/323329) of 4 modules that show related content